# Reading Multiple Files Java

Tags: java, file

I'm new here, and I got a problem when I'm trying to read a file.

Here is my code

```
public void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        if(Board.state == Board.STATE.LEVEL1)
        {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("D://OOP Photos//Map.txt"));
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        if(Board.state == Board.STATE.LEVEL2)
        {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("D://OOP Photos//Map1.txt"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error loading MAP !!! ");
    }

    try
    {
        if(Board.state == Board.STATE.LEVEL3)
        {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("D://OOP Photos//Map2.txt"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error loading MAP !!! ");
    }

}
```

If I comment out the if statement it is okay, but if I leave it there, it will throw a `NullPointerException` in the next method:

```
public void readFile()
{
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(scan.hasNext())
            {
                Map[i] = scan.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me ?

Thank You :)

Comment: scan is most likely null, what is the value of `Board.state` (also why is this static?)

Comment: state is a enum from the class Board , it helps me keeping the states of the game. i am traying to make a maze game , and these are my maps

Comment: Put everything in a single try-catch, combine the ifs into an exclusive if-else-if - you will quickly see the problem.

Comment: Tried but same problem apeared...

Comment: Didn't say it would be fixed, but you should be able to see why `scan` is null. See my answer for a different way to structure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String filename;
    if(Board.state == Board.STATE.LEVEL1) {
        filename = "D://OOP Photos//Map1.txt";
    }
    else if (Board.state == Board.STATE.LEVEL2) {
        filename = "D://OOP Photos//Map2.txt";
    }
    else if (Board.state == Board.STATE.LEVEL3) {
        filename = "D://OOP Photos//Map3.txt";
    }
    readFile(filename);
}

public void readFile(String filename) { 
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));

        int i = 0;
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            Map[i] = scan.next();
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error loading MAP !!! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working now , but have to solve some mouselisteners issues now , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before each IF statement simply print out the values of `Board.state` and `Board.STATE.LEVELx`? That will tell you exactly why your IFs are all false. Or just set a breakpoint and inspect the values.

Also try changing your `==` in the IFs to `.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your app logic makes me confused. Why not jsut make simple public Scanner openFile(String filePath) method, with one try / catch block, with one `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filePath))`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to consider:

```
public static class Board {

    // I'm assuming this is what's happening?
    public static State state = State.LEVEL1;

    public enum State {

        LEVEL1("Map.txt"), LEVEL2("Map1.txt"), LEVEL3("Map2.txt");

        private final String fileName;

        private State(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }
    }
};

public void openFile() {

    if (Board.state == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("board state not set");

    File file = new File("D:/OOP Photos/", Board.state.getFileName());

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {

        // do the scanning

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        // handle file not found
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle other errors
    }
}
```